# Django: Templates for loop not looping through list

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I don't know why, but my Django loop is not outputting anything. Here is the relevant code.

My AbstractUser class consists of these two methods:

```
def get_followers(self):
    return [user for user in self.followers.all()]

def get_following(self):
    return [user for user in self.following.all()]
```

My views:

```
class UserFollowingView(View):
    def get(self, request, username):
        user = get_object_or_404(apps.get_model('users', 'User'), username=username)
        context = {
            'username': user.username,
            'following': user.get_following(),
        }
        return render(request, 'core/user_following.html', context)


class UserFollowersView(View):
    def get(self, request, username):
        user = get_object_or_404(apps.get_model('users', 'User'), username=username)
        context = {
            'username': user.username,
            'followers': user.get_followers(),
        }
        return render(request, 'core/user_followers.html', context)
```

My templates:

user_following.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User | {{ username }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ username }} | Following</h1><hr/>

    {% for user in user_following %}
        <h3>{{ user.username }}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

user_followers.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User | {{ username }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ username }} | Followers</h1><hr/>

    {% for user in user_followers %}
        <h3>{{ user.username }}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Neither the user_following.html or user_followers.html files are working

I have made sure that each user does have followers/following (so the lists are populated), but for some reason the loop is not running. I'm getting no errors.

```
>>> a = User.objects.get(username="Test")
>>> a.get_followers()
[<User: Test2>, <User: Test3>]
>>>
```

See the Output:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il4NH.png)

Comment: You don't need list comprehension in your `get_followers` and `get_following` methods.  You can use `list(self.followers.all())` and `list(self.following.all())`.

Comment: `user_following` and `user_followers` are not present in template `context`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used both `user_following` and `user_followers` as standalone variables in your template; but they are not, they are methods on User. However, you have passed `following` and `followers` variables into your context; perhaps you meant to use those instead?

(Note that neither of those methods do anything useful at all; they are exactly equivalent to calling `user.followers.all()` or `user.following.all()`, so you might as well do that in your views or templates.)

Comment: Thanks! I have changed that now! Sorry for the stupid mistake.